# Rust compiling is very slow on Docker with `cargo watch`

Tags: docker, rust, docker-compose, rust-cargo

I am trying to setup a rust environment for development in docker.

My `Dockerfile` is

```
FROM rust:1.64 as dev
WORKDIR /src

RUN cargo install cargo-watch

ARG PORT=8800
EXPOSE $PORT
ENV PORT $PORT

CMD ["cargo", "watch", "-x", "run", "-w", "src"]
```

and my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  server:
    build: 
      context: ./packages/server
      target: dev
      args:
        PORT: 8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./packages/server:/src
```

For reference, my file structure is this :

```
root/
  packages/
    server/
      src/
        main.rs
      Cargo.lock
      Cargo.toml
      Dockerfile
  docker-compose.yml
```

So, very simple and it does work. However, when I edit the file, it automatically recompile and it takes about 1m30s, while when I'm running it directly on my computer, it takes 1s.

What could I change to make it faster ?

Thanks!

Edit: before anyone asks, I give Docker 14 GB of memory and 6 CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try cache your build folder?

```
version: "3"

services:
  server:
    image: rust:1-slim
    volumes:
      - ./.cargo/registry:/usr/local/cargo/registry
      - ./.target:/root/target
      - ./packages/server:/src
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - CARGO_TARGET_DIR=/root/target
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        cargo watch \
          -x run \
          -w Cargo.toml \
          -w src
```